# python dataframe automatically convert numeric columns as float but don't drop non-numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numeric

I have created the following function to take a data frame, convert numeric columns d-type to numeric. This is doing good job but the problem is, it drops the non-numeric columns as well, which I don't want to. Because, those columns carry some important information as well.

```
def convert_dataframe_to_numeric_type(df):
    def is_it_a_number(x):
      try:
        float(x)
        return True
      except:
        return False
    df = df[df.applymap(is_it_a_number)]
    df = df.dropna(how='all',axis=1)
    # after converting all non-numeric elements, transform them to numeric
    df = df.transform(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')
    return df
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to convert `object` or `string` columns to `float`? Or are you trying to determine the contents of mixed columns? Why not use `astype` or `convert_dtypes` ? Please post an example of what you want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just have a big data frame of mixed content: numeric columns, non-numeric columns. When I import it, all columns are object type. There are many columns. I don't want to look through each column. Rather, automate it.

Comment: Why not call [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) then? Or [infer_objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) Have you tried them?

Comment: I posted examples how to convert types with a single call. No loops

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to convert to numeric and check for nulls won't work. Almost all data files will have missing numeric values, which will appear as `NA`. Data loading functions like [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will generate NAs for every empty field *and* common NaN markers

> By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘None’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.

Besides, trying to convert all the values in a series and *then* check if  any failed does the same job *twice*. Pandas has built-in methods to detect/convert types that will stop immediately if conversion fails.

One option is [infer_object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html), which tries to detect the types of any `object` Series. Another option is [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) which will try to find the best type for the values.

Using this dataframe, where everything is `object` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "b": pd.Series(["x", "y", "z"], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "c": pd.Series([True, False, np.nan], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "d": pd.Series(["h", "i", np.nan], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "e": pd.Series([10, np.nan, 20], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "f": pd.Series([np.nan, 100.5, 200], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
    }
)
```

`infer_objects()` produces these types:

```
df_i=df.infer_objects()
df_i.dtypes
-----------------------
a      int64
b     object
c     object
d     object
e    float64
f    float64
dtype: object
```

While `convert_dtypes` goes deeper :

```
df_c=df.convert_dtypes()
df_c.dtypes
------------------------
a      Int64
b     string
c    boolean
d     string
e      Int64
f    Float64
```